# How to hide elements if a page is opened in a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

jQuery

```
$('a.popup').click(function(){
    window.open( this.href, 'Page title', 'width=600, height=650' );
    return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="popup" href="sample.html">
```

I want to hide the header and footer if my `sample.html` page is opened in a popup window. Can I add a class name to the `<html>` or `<body>` to the popup?, so I can add the CSS rules. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from `sample.html` in the `<head>` section just check if `window.opener` exists, e.g.

```
<script>
   if (window.opener) {
      /* i'm a popup, add "popup" class to <html> element */
      document.documentElement.className += " popup";
   }
</script>
```

then you can set your own CSS style using class `.popup`, e.g.

```
header { display: block; }
.popup header { display: none; }
```